# Windows luarocks

Tags: windows-10, lua

I have run out of patience with this problem and have turned to this community for help. I am trying to install `luafilesystem` and `luacheck` from `luarocks` and am only getting errors with anything I try.

I fresh installed `lua` version `5.3.0` and am using a visual studio admin prompt (so, `cl` is defined and ready to go). When I execute the install `luarocks install luafilesystem` it chucks an error:

```
Setting environment for using Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 x64 tools.

C:\WINDOWS\system32>luarocks install luafilesystem
Installing https://luarocks.org/luafilesystem-1.6.3-2.src.rock
cl /nologo /MD /O2 -c -Fosrc/lfs.obj -IC:/Program Files (x86)/Lua/5.3/include src/lfs.c
lfs.c
link -dll -def:lfs.def -out:lfs.dll C:/Program Files (x86)/Lua/5.3/bin/lua53.dll src/lfs.obj
Microsoft (R) Incremental Linker Version 10.00.40219.01
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

C:\Program Files (x86)\Lua\5.3\bin\lua53.dll : fatal error LNK1107: invalid or corrupt file: cannot read at 0x340

Error: Build error: Failed compiling module lfs.dll
```

Comment: You need use lua53.lib file. in config.lua/config-5.3 file.

Comment: I was unable to solve it with lua 5.3, but was easy with the 5.1 version bundled in the LuaRocks zip file.